# .net API throwing exception "JSON integer is too large or small for an Int32. Path 'item_id', line 1, position 1486"

Tags: podio

I'm using the .net client library, v1.5.9 which is the latest version, and am receiving the following error when attempting to add a new item on the ItemService:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: JSON integer 2151368024 is too large or small for an Int32. Path 'item_id', line 1, position 1486.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseReadNumber(ReadType readType, Char firstChar, Int32 initialPosition)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseNumber(ReadType readType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadNumberValue(ReadType readType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsInt32()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonConverter[] converters)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonConverter[] converters)
   at PodioAPI.Utils.JSONSerializer.Deserilaize[T](String json)
   at PodioAPI.Podio.Request[T](RequestMethod requestMethod, String url, Object requestData, Object options)
   at PodioAPI.Podio.Post[T](String url, Object requestData, Object options)
   at PodioAPI.Services.ItemService.AddNewItem(Int32 appId, Item item, Nullable`1 spaceId, Boolean silent, Boolean hook)
```

This is because the ItemId property is an int instead of long.

The client library hasn't been updated in years and it's been marked as archived now so I can't PR a fix.

Is there a way around this issue or do I have to replace the client library in my code with my own implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue by downloading the source code of the library, add the local reference and change the data type from int to long.

https://github.com/podio/podio-dotnet

But it seems there is only asynchronous version available (even the Podio .NET project is async), you may need to change the way you call the functions a bit.

Comment: I thought this would be the case. Thanks, I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: I had to patch the Java library myself too in this exact same way. They overflowed integer bounds, and provide zero support for their libraries. I have an open support issue with them, and all they did was correlate my problem with a known issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have exectly the same issue with podio.ItemService.FilterItems()

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)